# Using android:elevation makes a TextView disappear

Tags: android, android-xml, android-elevation

I have this `RelativeLayout` with only two views. Please see below what I have tried:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:elevation="4dp"/> //Below TextView disappear

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The TextView has set a negative `layout_marginTop` so it can be displayed over the image. Everything works fine till I set the elevation property. Once I set it, the below TextView disappears. How to stop this from happening?

Comment: @GulshanYadav I tried to change the order but it didn't work. Any other idea? Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok. I've edited the code try using CardView instead of ImageView in some versions elevation not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Add `android:elevation="5dp"` into the TextView in your layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
        android:elevation="5dp"/> // Add this line
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can follow [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/mastering-shadows-in-android-e883ad2c9d5b) link to see how `android:elevation` work in Android.

Comment: 4dp is sufficient.  Having the TextView appear below the ImageView in the XML will have it display on top.

Answer (score 0):

Use CardView instead.
Hope this work.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"        
app:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What i understand is you are trying to add text below image right??

Comment: No, it doesn't work either with the `CardView`. Once I set the elevation the TextView disappears :(

Comment: I am trying to add a text above the image and set the elevation to create that shadow to the image.

Comment: I don't need the elevation on the TextView, I need it on the ImageView. Does the elevation has something to do with setting backgrounds in those views? Check my edited question.

Comment: You're trying to create a shadow effect to the ImageView??

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. Is something wrong with that?

Comment: Ok. Then you should use CardView. Forget about elevation.

Comment: You need to add dependencies in build.gradle for CardView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191872/discussion-between-gulshan-yadav-and-asyl-paitesh).

Comment: I know, I'll try and get you back.

Comment: Your solution using a CardView solved this but in totally different way so I'm still curious why that didin't work. I wait a few more days maybe someone knows the reason why that didn't work and if I don't get any other better answer I'll accept your answer. Anyway, thanks for your time!